# Label map provided by landmarks module on Tensorflow Hub does not match model output

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to use landmark models on tensorflow hub provided at https://tfhub.dev/google/on_device_vision/classifier/landmarks_classifier_asia_V1/1

It says that the output is "prediction:logits: A vector of 99543 similarity scores". However, my out put shape is (1, 98960).

The label map file has 99543 lines which is aligned with the instruction, but the output size does not match the map file.

The predict result is far from accurate, claims an image of Oriental Tower as The Israel Museum with 0.76 score.

My input image is preprocessed to be [321, 321, 3], scaled to [0, 1] per instruction.

What could be wrong? Is it the model/labelmap issue or there is something wrong with my attempting?

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import pandas as pd

IMAGE_HEIGHT = 321
IMAGE_WIDTH = 321

def load_img(path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH])
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img) / 255.0
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, 0)
    return img

module_handle = "https://tfhub.dev/google/on_device_vision/classifier/landmarks_classifier_asia_V1/1"

detector = hub.KerasLayer(module_handle, output_key='predictions:logits')

image_path = 'xxx'

img = load_img(image_path)

output_tensor = detector(img)

output_tensor.shape
```

Which gives the result:
(1, 98960)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2021-03-18, the inconsistencies in the labelmaps have been fixed and an update for the model documentation (i.e. that the length of the output vector should actually be 98960 instead of 99543) is on the way. You can already re-download the labelmap files, which are referenced on the model pages on [tfhub.dev](https://tfhub.dev). Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the fix!